# Apollo-IOS build error "Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code"

Tags: swift, apollo-ios

I'm trying to build a sample Apollo-IOS on Xcode 10. I have followed all the step describe in the docs:

[Apolo-IOS getting started](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/ios/installation.html)

There is an error as bellow

```
++ npx --no-install apollo codegen:generate --queries=./GraphQL/Queries.graphql --schema=schema.json API.swift --passthroughCustomScalars
[?25l[22:26:11] Loading Apollo config [started]
[22:26:11] Loading Apollo config [completed]
[22:26:11] Resolving GraphQL document sets and dependencies [started]
[22:26:11] Scanning for GraphQL queries (1 found) [title changed]
[22:26:11] Scanning for GraphQL queries (1 found) [completed]
[22:26:11] Generating query files [started]
[22:26:11] Generating query files with 'swift' target [title changed]
[22:26:11] Generating query files with 'swift' target [failed]
[22:26:11] → Cannot read property 'getType' of undefined
[?25hTypeError: Cannot read property 'getType' of undefined
    at typeFromAST (/Volumes/Data/OneDrive/IOS/Source/GraphQL/JediArchives/JediArchives-Final/node_modules/graphql/utilities/typeFromAST.js:41:19)
    at TypeInfo.enter (/Volumes/Data/OneDrive/IOS/Source/GraphQL/JediArchives/JediArchives-Final/node_modules/graphql/utilities/TypeInfo.js:153:74)
    at Object.enter (/Volumes/Data/OneDrive/IOS/Source/GraphQL/JediArchives/JediArchives-Final/node_modules/graphql/language/visitor.js:363:16)
    at Object.visit (/Volumes/Data/OneDrive/IOS/Source/GraphQL/JediArchives/JediArchives-Final/node_modules/graphql/language/visitor.js:254:26)
    at getValidationErrors (/Volumes/Data/OneDrive/IOS/Source/GraphQL/JediArchives/JediArchives-Final/node_modules/apollo/lib/validation.js:21:15)
    at Object.validateQueryDocument (/Volumes/Data/OneDrive/IOS/Source/GraphQL/JediArchives/JediArchives-Final/node_modules/apollo/lib/validation.js:26:30)
    at Object.generate [as default] (/Volumes/Data/OneDrive/IOS/Source/GraphQL/JediArchives/JediArchives-Final/node_modules/apollo/lib/generate.js:19:18)
    at Task.task (/Volumes/Data/OneDrive/IOS/Source/GraphQL/JediArchives/JediArchives-Final/node_modules/apollo/lib/commands/codegen/generate.js:98:64)
    at Promise.resolve.then.then.skipped (/Volumes/Data/OneDrive/IOS/Source/GraphQL/JediArchives/JediArchives-Final/node_modules/listr/lib/task.js:167:30)
[?25hCommand PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

Seem like my `Queries.graphql` and `schema.json` is in the correct place and can be found by the run script. Anyone know what is the error and how to resolve (I have updated to latest `Apollo-Cli` which is 1.9.2)

Comment: Did you got the solution??

Comment: Hi I think need to check the location of  schema.json. I got it working by put all in the root folder

Comment: So u put API.swift , schema.json and .graphql everything in root folder??

Comment: Only schematic.json and .graphql file. Important is the scheme.json syntax. I got it by execute Apollo download scheme command

Answer (score 12):

I had the same problem.
I checkout the **Run script only when installing**  and I resolved the problem. 
Check that you tick on that checkbox **Run script only when installing** [image]

Comment: Hì thank for the response. What if we change our GraphQL file and regenerate?

Comment: Actually I am also stucking with some problem in Apollo GraphQL including this issue and I resolved it with checkout **Run script only when installing** so I am not sure about your question....

Comment: Do not change anything that is created by Apollo. If you'll lose those changes when Apollo recreate the file during it's prebuild script. Specifically the API.swift that it generates.

Comment: problem will solved but API.Swift Is Not  genreated

Answer (score 2):

For me Xcode13. Tick the check box of "For install builds only" under build base. working fine

[image]

Comment: That worked. But why?

Answer (score -1):

In 2023 with xCode 14+ and installing apollo through the package manager, it stills the same solution
Since i cant post an image because im not level 10, i just wanted to let you know that u still need to mark the checkbox:

> For install build only

-Peace

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34615096)