# Apollo IOS - Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

Tags: swift, xcode, graphql, apollo, swift5

I have an app that uses graphql and connected to Apollo. Everything works as expected until one day it produces this error (please see image). I follow the solution found in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52951622/apollo-ios-build-error-command-phasescriptexecution-failed-with-a-nonzero-exit)

I enabled the `run script for install builds only` on my build phase settings. My apps runs again as expected but whenever I try to archive my app, I encountered the error again. I tried to clean my project, reintall pod. delete worxspace and generate again but still encounter the same error. I dont understand why I keep having this error. Please help. Thank you

[image]